# Custom __str__ and __repr__ are not working

Tags: python

I am trying to convert an output such as :

```
decrypt : <torfuncs.TorHop instance at 0x7f44babb8440>
```

into something a bit more readable, the result should be a string from array. I have defined `__str__` and `__repr__` but even with these I am still getting the result above. What am I doing wrong?

```
class TorCircuit():
    def __init__(self, sock, circid):
        self.hops = []
        self.circId = circid
        self.socket = sock
        self.tempX = 0
        self.packetSendCount = 0
        self.cookie = []

    def __str__(self, hop):    
        return 'hop #%d' %  self.hops

    def __repr__(self, hop):
        return 'hop #%d' %  self.hops

    def decrypt(self, relayCell):
        for hop in self.hops:
            print "decrypt :", str(hop)
            relayCell = hop.decrypt(relayCell)
            if relayCell[1]==0 and relayCell[2]==0:
                return relayCell
        return relayCell
```

What I am trying to print out is the hop currently in use for the decryption

edit TorHop

```
class TorHop:

    def __str__(self):    
        return 'hop #' %  self.hop

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'hop #' %  self.hop

    def __init__(self, KH, Df, Db, Kf, Kb):
        self.KH = KH
        self.Df = Df
        self.Db = Db
        self.Kf = Kf
        self.Kb = Kb

        self.fwdSha = SHA.new()
        self.fwdSha.update(Df)
        self.bwdSha = SHA.new()
        self.bwdSha.update(Db)

        ctr = Counter.new(128,initial_value=0)
        self.fwdCipher = AES.new(Kf, AES.MODE_CTR, counter=ctr)
        ctr = Counter.new(128,initial_value=0)
        self.bwdCipher = AES.new(Kb, AES.MODE_CTR, counter=ctr)
    def encrypt(self, data):
        return self.fwdCipher.encrypt(data)
    def decrypt(self, data):
        return self.bwdCipher.decrypt(data)
```

with this I now get:

```
AttributeError: TorHop instance has no attribute 'hops'
```

Comment: At one point you have `self.hop` instead of `self.hops`. Another issue is that you're trying to use `%d`, which is intended for integers, to print out what appears to be a list. That's going to fail.

Comment: You need to add the `__str__` and `__repr__` definitions to the `TorHop` class, not to the `TorCircuit` class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to think that using `str(hop)` in the `TorCircuit.decrypt()` class translates to `self.__str__(hop)`. *This is not the case*. It translates to `hop.__str__()` instead.

In other words, don't put these methods on the `TorCircuit` class, put them on the `TorHop` class instead.

When you do add them to `TorHop`, take into account that `__str__` and `__repr__` do not take arguments. Remove the `hop` argument; `self` is the `TorHop` instance:

```
def __str__(self):    
    return 'hop #%d' %  self.hop

def __repr__(self):
    return 'hop #%d' %  self.hop
```

I'd keep the `__repr__` to something a little more useful for debugging:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return '<TorHop(%d)>' % self.hop
```

perhaps.

Next, you appear to expect the hops to be numbered. They are not. You can alter your loop to add a number *before* the value printed for the `TorHop` object, using the [`enumerate()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for i, hop in enumerate(self.hops):
    print "decrypt: hop #{} {}".format(i, hop)
```

This will print `decrypt: hop #0`, then `decrypt: hop #1`, etc., followed by the result of `hop.__str__()`.

Comment: @user3842234: where is your `TorHop` class then?

Comment: Added above, got a new error since adding to the tor hop class

Comment: @user3842234: that's because your `TorHop` class *has no `hop` or `hops` attribute*.

Comment: Yes the self.hops = [] is in TorCircuit is there any way to get the data from this in torHop ? if that makes sense

Comment: @user3842234: `__str__` can only make use of attributes on the `TorHop` object itself. Either give those objects the hop number, or add numbers in your loop as shown.

Comment: Thanks a lot for al your help, just one final question,where should the enumerate be placed as im still having isues getting anything at all to be printed out atm

Comment: @user3842234: where you use `for hop in self.hops` in `TorCircuit .decrypt`.